# HTML. Dos bloques <div> se quedan a distinta altura. Como ponerlos al mismo nivel

Tags: css, html5, imagen

Estoy haciendo una web con html y css. Quiero poner un encabezado. El código HTML5 que empleo es el siguiente:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="imagenMuslito">
            <img src="muslito25.jpg" alt="Dibujo muslito pollo">
        </div>
        <div class="elMuslito">
            <h1>El muslito</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.elMuslito {
  /*float: left;*/
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.imagenMuslito {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Con el CSS ahora solo pretendo que estén al mismo nivel Imagen y texto. Pero cuando le doy más margin-top al H1 tambien lo toma la imagen. Lo cual no entiendo porque están en bloques div diferentes.

Inserto la imagen del resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como los pongo al mismo nivel?? Porque el código que empleo no los pone al mismo nivel??

Comment: https://es.acervolima.com/como-colocar-dos-div-uno-al-lado-del-otro-de-la-misma-altura-usando-css/#:~:text=Python%20JavaScript%20PHP-,%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo%20colocar%20dos%20div%20uno%20al%20lado%20del%20otro%20de,en%20formato%20lado%20a%20lado. Aquí un ejemplo claro para lo que necesitas, aunque yo te recomendaría investigar Bootstrap, te va a facilitar un poco la vida :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

es mas simple de lo que intentas necesitas hacer esto:

```
<section>
    <div class="imagenMuslito">
        <img src="muslito25.jpg" alt="Dibujo muslito pollo">
    </div>
    <div class="elMuslito">
        <h1>El muslito</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

y en el css solo esto:

```
section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

luego ya puedes perzonalizarlo como quieras.

Comment: Perfecto tio!!!! Gracias